# R - Random number generation in ggplot and Shiny

Tags: r, random, shiny

I am building a plot of Net Present Value (NPV), using [FinCal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FinCal/index.html) package, and its odds. For the NPV, the cash-flows are simulated using a triangular distribution for sales, normal distribution for costs and so on. So, here is a snippet of what I am doing:

```
npvCdf <- function(n) {
  N <- sort(n)
  P <- ecdf(N)
  return(P)
}

makePlot <- function(C, m) {
  N <- m$NPV / C$MILLION
  P <- npvCdf(N)
  #
  # NPV distribution curve
  n <- sort(N)
  p <- P(n) * 100
  df <- data.frame(npv = n, odds = p)
  #
  # Points of interest
  o <- C$NPV_BREAK_EVEN_WORST_ODDS
  q <- round((quantile(n, o)), C$DIGITS)
  e <- C$NPV_BREAK_EVEN_VALUE
  b <- P(e) * 100   # THIS IS THE ERROR I CANT FIGURE OUT
  w <- o * 100
  s <- getBreakEven(C, m)
  #
  # Labels
  npvOdds <- paste("Odds of break-even : ", b, "%")
  salesThresh <- paste("Sales threshold : ", s)
  worstCase <-
    paste("Worst case (@ 5% odds) : ", q, "million")
  #
  # Make plot
  #
  g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = npv, y = odds)) +
    geom_line(colour = "blue") +
    labs(title = "NPV and Odds") +
    labs(x = "NPV (million)") +
    labs(y = "Percent (%)") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = e,
               colour = "red",
               linetype = "longdash") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = b,
               colour = "green",
               linetype = "longdash") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = q,
               colour = "green",
               linetype = "dotdash") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = w,
               colour = "red",
               linetype = "dotdash")
```

The `C` is a data frame of all the constants that are used for calculations of cash-flows, NPV calculations, etc. For example, `C$MILLION=1000000` used to divide NPV for simpler representation. The `m` is a data-frame of sales, cash-flows and NPV per simulation. The simulations are used for cash-flows (triangular distribution), variable cost (normal distribution) and so on.

And, here is the Shiny code that uses the above snippet.

```
library(shiny)
source("../npd-c.R")
# Define server logic 
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$npdPlot <- renderPlot({

    C <- data.frame(2017,5000,1000000,3,100,500000,0.0,0.05,0.1,
                    input$salesRange[1],
                    input$salesRange[2],
                    input$salesMode,
                    input$demDeclMean,
                    input$demDeclSd,
                    input$varCostMean,
                    input$varCostSd,
                    input$fixedCostRange[1],
                    input$fixedCostRange[2]
                    )
    names(C) <-
      c(
        "SEED",
        "ITERATIONS",
        "MILLION",
        "DIGITS",
        "PRICE",
        "OUTLAY",
        "NPV_BREAK_EVEN_VALUE",
        "NPV_BREAK_EVEN_WORST_ODDS",
        "HURDLE_RATE",
        "SALES_TRIANG_MIN",
        "SALES_TRIANG_MAX",
        "SALES_TRIANG_MODE",
        "DEM_DECL_FACTOR_MEAN",
        "DEM_DECL_FACTOR_SD",
        "VAR_COST_RATE_MEAN",
        "VAR_COST_RATE_SD",
        "FIX_COST_RATE_MIN",
        "FIX_COST_RATE_MAX"
      )

    n <- npd(C,-1)
    g <- makePlot(C,n)
    g
  })
})
```

The problem is as follows.

The same code when run in R, I get the plot right in terms of the NPV curve, horizontal and vertical lines. Whereas, when run as a Shiny application, the horizontal and vertical lines are hugely displaced. This is despite, hiving of the NPV and cash-flows code into a separate .R file and **setting the same seed value** for both the Shiny and non-shiny versions. For example, `P(0)=40.07` without Shiny and `P(0)=4.7` with Shiny application.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the data we need to see the problem. Note that the phrase "horizontal and vertical lines are hugely displaced" can mean a lot of things - I do not know what you mean. How about a reproducible example? Or if that seems too hard then a snippet of your data and a couple of screen shots would help immensely.

Comment: I did mention that P (0) is hugely different in the cases of Shiny and not Shiny. I can upload plots in a hour time.

Comment: Here are the plots - with and without Shiny. Notice how the curve looks same but, the intersection of horizontal and vertical lines are off. https://imagebin.ca/v/3K47HvFC6Gt8 (with Shiny) and https://imagebin.ca/v/3K46LXO7ZvKs (without Shiny)

Comment: Make any progress?

Comment: No. Following here after I was asked to do on Shiny GitHub pages. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/shiny-discuss/tsrtgpbM3zQ

Comment: He is saying the same thing as me. Your models in the two cases are different and that is causing the difference, not the random number generation. If you publish the whole code I could have a look.

Comment: This is the code: https://github.com/ProgramErgoSum/npv

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me say this is pretty useful code. It is a nice represenation of a monte-carlo simulation using NPV and I like the plots. It is a post I am pretty sure I will refer back to.

I think I see where the problem is though, it is basically more a matter of mis-interpretation and one small programming error.

The stated problem is that these plots are not showing the same results although they should be. The blue ecdf-NPV curves do look at first glance to be the same:

Shiny version:

[image]

Stand alone version:

[image]

However if you look carefully, you will see that in fact they are not the same, the expected NPV value (50 percent) in the first case is about 1.5 million, whereas it is only about 0.2 in the second case.

The curves look the same, but they are not. The other point is that there is an error in one of the calculations further confusing things. The "Odds of break-even" are incorrectly calculated and are actually the "Odds of losing money".

The correct calculation should be:

```
b <- (1-P(e)) * 100
```

And the correct odds of breaking even in the first case would be around 60%, and in the second case around 95%, which matches up with the expected NPV as well.

Comment: Glad you like the code! I know that the curves are different. That is exactly what I want to know - same seed values generating similar looking curves but, shifted along the x-axis. The `C$NPV_BREAK_EVEN_VALUE` will be set to 0.0. The idea is to find the odds of breaking even i.e. `P(0)`. And, it is wildly off for both the scenarios mentioned. Also, the NPV at worst case odds `P(0.05)` are also similarly wildly off.

Comment: It is definitely not the seed or the random numbers. You can prove that to yourself by playing with the seed on either model, the results should change very little, or you have programmed something very wrong. There are differences in your model - probably in the parameters.